# Mercedes C180 (W204) dash symbol

Tags: mercedes-benz, dashboard

Does anyone know what this symbol means? Could not find it anywhere in the instructions manual or online.

[image: W204 Dashboard]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The symbol is for "Speed limit assist" and is based of a forward facing camera that allows detection of the speed limit and then possibly displays this on the multifunctional display.

Information can be found at [this site](http://www4.mercedes-benz.com/manual-cars/ba/cars/w204/en/manual_base.shtml), under the "Steering Wheel( 12 button multifunction...)" > "Assistance menu" and subsequent links from within page.

Answer (score 3):

@Solar Mike's answer inspired my finding this:

According to [this website](https://www.gofar.co/car-warning-lights/car-warning-light-symbols-and-indicators/)

this symbol means speed limiter - which seems close to yours - at least the lollipop part of it.

[image]

Comment: The merc speed limiter is annoyingly easy to turn on by mistake. You push the cruise control stalk in to switch between cruise and limiter modes.

Answer (score 2):

My best educated guess is an excess speed warning.

Whether the limit is user settable or not is a different question.